# How to send draftjs data to mongodb

Tags: reactjs, json, mongodb, mongoose, draftjs

I want to make text editor and save the written data to a server (Mongodb) with its styling, then show the saved written data in the styled way, I did the coding for the editor but the problem now is how to send the data to the server. POST

Here is the code for **TextEditor.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";

import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

export default class TextEditor extends Component {
  state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
  };

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    console.log(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        />
        <textarea
          disabled
          value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Write Page **Write.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import TextEditor from '../../components/TextEditor/TextEditor';

export default function Write() {
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState('');
  const { user } = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newPost = {
      username: user.username,
      desc,
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/posts', newPost);
      window.location.replace('/post/' + res.data._id);
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  return (
    <div className='write'>
      <form className='writeForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextEditor
          placeholder='Write your story'
          type='text'
          className='writeInput writeText'
          onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button className='writeSubmit' type='submit'>
          نشر
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Post.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  desc: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

I know that I have to use `JSON.stringify(convertToRaw())` and `convertFromRaw()` but I didn't know where to use them, it's been now week and I'm still trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**It should be like something this.**

```
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";

const data = convertFromRaw(response);

const state = EditorState.createWithContent(data);

<Editor editorState={state} readOnly={true} />
```